# Tab Bar Controller Items Missing on Storyboard

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uitabbaritem, ios7.1

I am not really sure what is happening with my xcode project. I am unable to edit the tab bar items in the story board. They are all greyed out as you can see below. 
Could you please let me know what might be causing this?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem here...did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Still the same. I can only manage them via the object tree

Comment: yeah, me too, it happens since i updated to Xcode 5.1

Comment: Creating a new project from scratch finally so this issue is irrelevant:) Need to code it in swift

Comment: try adding images to your tab bar items. Then your tab bar should not be grayed out. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer solved the problem. You can still see the icons and titles when you click and drag it.